Соответствие кода Laravel принципам SOLID
Соответствует ли код принципам SOLID?
Я создал следующие интефейсы:

app/Interfaces/CarCreateInterface.php

<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

use App\Models\Car;

interface CarCreateInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return Car
     */
    public function create(string $title): Car;
}


app/Interfaces/CarExistenceCheckerInterface.php

<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

interface CarExistenceCheckerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists(string $title): bool;
}



app/Interfaces/CarManagementInterface.php

<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

use App\Models\Car;

interface CarManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return Car
     */
    public function createIfNotExists(string $title): Car;
}

Затем я создал следующие сервисы:

app/Services/CarCreateService.php

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\CarCreateInterface;
use App\Models\Car;

class CarCreateService implements CarCreateInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return Car
     */
    public function create(string $title): Car
    {
        $car= new Car();
        $car->title = $title;
        $car->save();

        return $car;
    }
}


app/Services/CarExistenceCheckerService.php

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\CarExistenceCheckerInterface;
use App\Models\Car;

class CarExistenceCheckerService implements CarExistenceCheckerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists(string $title): bool
    {
        return Car::where('title', $title)
            ->exists();
    }
}


app/Services/CarManagementService.php

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\CarCreateInterface;
use App\Interfaces\CarExistenceCheckerInterface;
use App\Interfaces\CarManagementInterface;
use App\Models\Car;
use Exception;

class CarManagementService implements CarManagementInterface
{
    protected CarExistenceCheckerInterface $car_existence_checker_service;
    protected CarCreateInterface $car_create_service;

    public function __construct(
        CarExistenceCheckerInterface $car_existence_checker_service,
        CarCreateInterface           $car_create_service,
    )
    {
        $this->car_existence_checker_service = $car_existence_checker_service;
        $this->car_create_service = $car_create_service;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return Car
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function createIfNotExists(string $title): Car
    {
        if ($this->car_existence_checker_service->exists($title)) {
            throw new Exception("Машина уже добавлена");
        }

        return $this->car_create_service->create($title);
    }
}


Меня смущает что функция в сервисе CarManagementService объединяет в себе два функционала, проверка на существование и добавление, не нарушает ли мой код этим принципы SOLID?

у вас цель то какая, как из простой вещи сделать монстра в 100500 классов?

Цель, архитектурно чистый и расширяемый код сделать

ну пока что у вас люто перегруженный, избыточно декомпозированный, код который долго расширяем, сложно понимаем, собственно ничего не делает но уже почти десяток классов генерирует.

Вы пытаетесь каждую функцию завернуть свой класс. SOLID разве это требует? Класс в себе должен содержать какой блок функций связанных между собой общей задачей. Создание машины и проверка ее наличия это  тесно связанные между собой вещи не надо их в принципе разделять. Вот если бы у вас в одном классе было создание машины, и какая-нить отправка писем о том что машина сгорела (при чем не само событие отправки, а вообще все общение с smtp сервером) вот это была бы проблема требующая декомпозиции.

вопрос также зачем вам интерфейсы. просто так? чтобы были? Вы планируете делать различные реализации каких то классов, которые будут реализовывать интерфейс с нуля? Если у вас одна реализация, или несколько реализаций, использующие наследование, то на кой тут интерфейс?

В данном случае не вижу особых поводов так дробить. Есть машина, есть сервис, который с ней работает, есть интерфейс, которому этот сервис следует. Чтобы разделять каждое действие с машиной на отдельные интерфейсы и сервисы нужна какая-то причина. Ну, например, если одно из действий выполняется очень часто, его нужно оптимизировать и разгрузить этот сервис от других действий. Можно ещё что-то придумать. Тут я никаких таких причин не вижу.


Меня смущает что функция в сервисе CarManagementService объединяет в себе два функционала, проверка на существование и добавление, не нарушает ли мой код этим принципы SOLID?

Давайте пройдемся по всем буквам.
SRP
Каждый класс должен решать только одну задачу, быть "ответственным" за что-то одно - наверное как раз вас это и смутило.
Основная ошибка — считать, что "единственная ответственность" относится только к функциональности класса, то есть класс должен выполнять лишь одно действие. Однако это упрощение не совсем верно.
Что говорит Роберт Мартин (создатель SOLID)?
SRP означает, что у класса должна быть только одна причина для изменения. Это связано не столько с функциональностью, сколько с контекстом ответственности. Разные аспекты кода могут меняться по разным причинам, и задача SRP — изолировать эти изменения (чтобы не было, что небольшое изменение требований порождало массу изменений в куче классов, а наоборот было локализовано).
Давайте подумаем - что может измениться в системе, что потребует изменение реализации CarManagementService? Очень мало кода, поэтому придумываю.

Добавить логирование действия по добавлению машины и уведомление об этом. Эти вещи прямо относятся к действию "добавить машину", поэтому могут быть встроены непосредственно в этот класс, и не нарушают SRP (даже подтверждают).
При добавлении прицепа увеличивать метрику "количество прицепов в системе" - это изменение НЕ потребует изменения CarManagementService - как раз SRP в действии. А вот если потребует - значит SRP нарушен.

Open/Closed Principle
Классы должны быть открыты для расширения, но закрыты для изменения.
Другими словами, добавление нового функционала не должно требовать изменения уже существующего кода.
Никаких нарушений я не вижу. Вот что чекаю:

private / final методы - их нет, можно расширять наследованием (но это не значит что если они есть - значит всё, нарушение, просто плюс к открытости)
Dependency Injection (DI) - зависимости внедрены (также относится к другому принципу - Dependency Inversion Principle), а также можно использовать полиморфизм. На деле это значит, что можно через зависимость подставить другой полиморфный класс, в котором, например, при "create" слать уведомление (на самом деле - лучше в этом классе, либо через Event/Listener, но не буду углубляться)

Вообще кода очень мало, поэтому эти 2 пункта - просто высосаны из пальца. Когда кода (и требований) будет значительно больше, будет о чем говорить.
Например, добавить создание события (патерн Event/Listener) на действие создания. Если добавить - будет плюс к открытости. Но также минус в качестве оверинжиниринга. Тут важно найти некоторый баланс между добавлением всяких Event/хуков/колбеков и оверинжирингом - это приходит с опытом. Вот мои рецепты:

Если делаете composer-пакет / библиотеку, то добавляйте - люди не смогут поменять что лежит в vendor, но через события смогут добавить свой функционал
Если это код, который завтра может быть снесен - не добавляйте
Если думаете, что код будет переиспользован, то добавляйте

Также если в базовом классе используется self::someMethod(), замените на static::someMethod() - Late Static Bindings позволит переопределить реализацию в потомке.
Liskov Substitution Principle
Не вижу наследования, поэтому ничего сказать нельзя.
Interface Segregation Principle
Вы нарезали функционал на тонкие интерфейсы, что согласуется.
Однако интерфейсы слишком тонкие - при таком подходе их будет очень много, избыточно много. Это одна крайность. Другая крайность - когда на большой сервис делается 1 интерфейс (и ISP соотвественно нарушается). Тут важен баланс, а также глубокое проникновение в предметную область.
Тут подходит паттерн repository.
Посмотрите vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth - там есть куча интерфейсов, которые относятся к одному домену/аспекту "авторизация", но нарезаны по функциональности:

Authenticatable - непосредственно авторизация
CanResetPassword - возможность сброса пароля (не во всех системах можно сбрасывать пароль - и это вынесено в отдельный интерфейс - тут как раз важно вникать в предметную область)
Guard - "защитник" - действия вокруг авторизованного/неавторизованного пользователя
MustVerifyEmail - необходимость подтверждать Email (опять же не всегда требуется, поэтому - отдельный интерфейс)
SupportsBasicAuth - поддержка basic-авторизации - по аналогии с MustVerifyEmail

DIP
Он у вас соблюден:

Есть зависимость от абстракций (конкретно - интерфейсы) в более высоком CarManagementService
Все сервисы зависят от абстракций, а не конкретных классов

Остальное (не критичное)
Замечание по DI
У вас зависимости в конструкторе, а значит что они создаются сервис-контейнером при создании класса. Однако $this->car_create_service->create($title) может никогда не вызываться. Поэтому лучше использовать app(CarCreateInterface::class)->....
Конкретно в данном случае это экономия на спичках (из соображения, что 99% будет вызываться), но в других случаях - лучшее решение. Также есть DI через методы-сеттеры - советую ознакомиться со всем списком вариантов.
Привязка к РСУБД
Есть жесткая сцепка с РСУБД из-за использования App\Models\Car в интерфейсе.
Если говорить не про SOLID, а про чистую архитектуру, то это нарушение - нужно абстрагироваться от фреймворка. Тут подходит шаблон repository + интерфейс "Машина".
Организация namespace
namespace App\Interfaces;
namespace App\Services;

Если ваша система вырастет до сотен тысяч строк кода, такая организация станет не удобной. В этом случае подходит доменная организация:

App\Domain\Car - интерфейсы домена "Машина"
App\Domain\Car\Models - модели
App\Domain\Car\Events - события
App\Domain\Car\Controllers - контроллеры
App\Domain\Car\FooBarSystem - интеграция с системой "FooBarSystem"

Рекомендую изучить Laravel Beyound CRUD (en) - очень хороший материал, использую практически все подходы на продакшн-системе.
Если сервис маленький и не будет расти - можете использовать "Ларовскую" схему организации классов.
Комментарии
На этом моменте я понял, что уже мой ответ походит на код-ревью :)
/**
 * @param string $title
 * @return Car
 */

Выкиньте эти комменты. Современные IDE и так все понимают, а вот вам придется поддерживать эти комменты.
Но есть редкие исключения - по этому моменту лучше прочитать любую книжку по чистому коду, глава "комментарии".
